# Поочередный вывод строк из ListBox в Label в таймере

Tags: delphi

Как реализовать поочередный вывод строк из ListBox в Label в обработчике таймера? И когда доходит до последней строки, начиналось по новой с первой строки.

Comment: Что конкретно у вас не получается?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью цикла:

```
for i = 0 to LB1.Count -1 do
label.cvaption = LB1[i]
```